# Recursively including all model subdirectories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, autoload, directory-structure

How do you load all directories recursively in the models and lib directories?  In application.rb, I have the lines:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', '{**}')]
```

but they only seem to add one level of model and lib subdirectories.

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

this should be helpful

```
 Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/","#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

enjoy! (:

Update:

Excellent question, posting example above i have simply referred to my recent project.

After making some tests, better understanding comes to me and it is great.

The main difference is of course neither in join method of File not config.root / Rails.root

Trailing '/' after '**' makes sense.

First one talks to match **only** directories when globbing.
 Second one talks do it **recursively**.

In your case this one could be also appropriate

```
Dir[ Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '**/') ]
```

Comment: Nice that worked... a little confused how `Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]` is different from `Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/"]`.  Thanks though

Comment: i've updated my answer with some explanation as it was big enough

Comment: I still don't get it. Then why would anybody use '{**}' instead of ' **/' ?